# pydev multithread debugging

Tags: python, pydev

I'm trying to debug an application which makes use of the pynetdicom library. I'm not sure how relevant that specific detail is, however what IS relevant is that it makes heavy use of multithreading to run background socket listener tasks without blocking the main thread. The storescp.py example can be used to reproduce this.

Whenever I place a breakpoint that gets encountered (regardless of what thread, main or child, it gets encountered in), I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1397, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "/Users/alexw/Development/Python/kreport2/KReport2/dicomdatascraper.py", line 183, in <module>
    oldDicomList = copy.copy(newData)
  File "/Users/alexw/Development/Python/kreport2/KReport2/dicomdatascraper.py", line 183, in <module>
    oldDicomList = copy.copy(newData)
  File "/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902/pysrc/pydevd_frame.py", line 135, in trace_dispatch
    self.doWaitSuspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902/pysrc/pydevd_frame.py", line 25, in doWaitSuspend
    self._args[0].doWaitSuspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 832, in doWaitSuspend
    self.processInternalCommands()
  File "/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 360, in processInternalCommands
    thread_id = GetThreadId(t)
  File "/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902/pysrc/pydevd_constants.py", line 140, in GetThreadId
    return thread.__pydevd_id__
  File "/Users/alexw/.virtualenvs/kreport2dev/devlibs/pynetdicom/source/netdicom/applicationentity.py", line 73, in __getattr__
    obj = eval(attr)()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__pydevd_id__' is not defined
```

My thought is that, perhaps, in order to make things work, PyDev monkey-patches a `__pydevd_id__` into spawned threads, however fails to patch those into *these* threads because they are, in fact, subclasses and not direct instances of `threading.Thread` (in this case, the worker is an instance of `class Association(threading.Thread):`).

Of course, I don't know PyDev well enough to confirm this theory, or else fix it. And it seems neither does the internet.

Is subclassing `Thread` so rarely used a pattern that it's simply not considered in the PyDev architecture? Without re-architecting the library, how could this issue be remedied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply needed to look harder at that traceback.

The pynetdicom library, in its subclassing of `threading.Thread`, overrode `__getattr__` and somewhat broke it. The problem was:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    #while not self.AssociationEstablished:
    #    time.sleep(0.001)
    obj = eval(attr)

    # do some stuff

    return obj
```

when a nonexistent attribute is passed, a NameError is raised. This isn't caught by pydev's monkeypatching routine (`if thread.__pydevd_id__ raises AttributeError, thread.__pydevd_id__ = stuff`)

The solution was to update that section thusly:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    #while not self.AssociationEstablished:
    #    time.sleep(0.001)
    try:
        obj = eval(attr)
    except NameError:
        raise AttributeError

    # do some stuff

    return obj
```

This intercepts the NameError and raises an AttributeError instead, as `__getattr__` should if the queried attribute doesn't exist.